# Como o PHP efetua limpeza do cache de sessão?

Tags: php, session

Em uma manutenção periódica de um servidor, identifiquei que arquivos de sessão antigos (com mais de dois anos de vida) ainda estavam presentes no servidor, ainda com informação contidas neles.

No **php.ini** do servidor, tenho essas configurações:

```ini
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.gc_probability = 0
session.gc_maxlifetime = 36000
```

Alguns scripts têm `ini_set` que sobrepõe o `session.gc_maxlifetime`, mas nunca são maiores que um mês.

Além disso, alguns scripts não deletam a sessão com `session_destroy()`.

Como o PHP limpa sessões antigas e não utilizadas mais? Como ele identifica as que "não foram mais utilizadas" ou ele não liga para isso?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O `session.gc_divisor` define a probabilidade do processo do GC (*garbage collection*) iniciar a cada inicialização de sessão (`session_start()`), a probabilidade é calculada `<gc_probability>/<gc_divisor>`, exemplo, se os valores forem `1/100` resultará em `1%` de chances a cada requisição (que iniciar uma sessão).

> Note: o valor padrão do `session.gc_divisor` é `100`
>
> Nota: se definir `session.gc_probability=0` você irá desligar o sistema baseado em probabilidades, o que irá depender de executar o GC de outra forma, com um script próprio, veja no final da resposta

O `session.gc_maxlifetime` especifica o número de segundos após o qual os dados serão vistos como *lixo* e potencialmente devem ser limpos, baseados no `<gc_probability>/<gc_divisor>`, citados anteriormente.

> Nota: o valor padrão do `session.gc_maxlifetime` é 1440 (24 minutos) para considerar uma sessão como possivelmente lixo

Resumindo para uma sessão ser considera lixo é preciso que os dados sejam mais antigos que o limite de `session.gc_maxlifetime` e depois disso o GC terá as chances de ser executado, a cada sessão iniciada, baseando-se nos valores padrões `1/100`, que por padrão será de *1%* do GC ser executado.

Note que `session_destroy()` pode causar efeitos colaterais, como condição corrida, quando há solicitações simultâneas, outras conexões podem sofrer perda repentina de dados de sessão, por exemplo, requisições HTTP. A condição corrida que pode ocorrer também poderá causar a criação de sessões ID desnecessariamente.

Note que o funcionamento do [ext/session/session.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/66aed3a86f2b9368888e22c30784286b3eeb24ad/ext/session/session.c#L361) atualmente é esse:

```c
static zend_long php_session_gc(bool immediate)
{
    int nrand;
    zend_long num = -1;

    /* GC must be done before reading session data. */
    if ((PS(mod_data) || PS(mod_user_implemented))) {
        if (immediate) {
            PS(mod)->s_gc(&PS(mod_data), PS(gc_maxlifetime), &num);
            return num;
        }
        nrand = (zend_long) ((float) PS(gc_divisor) * php_combined_lcg());
        if (PS(gc_probability) > 0 && nrand < PS(gc_probability)) {
            PS(mod)->s_gc(&PS(mod_data), PS(gc_maxlifetime), &num);
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

Note o parâmetro `immediate`, se ele for `false` irá executar a parte baseada na probabilidade:

```c
nrand = (zend_long) ((float) PS(gc_divisor) * php_combined_lcg());
if (PS(gc_probability) > 0 && nrand < PS(gc_probability)) {
    PS(mod)->s_gc(&PS(mod_data), PS(gc_maxlifetime), &num);
}
```

Se usar a função `session_gc()` no PHP, então irá executar o `immediate` será `true`, que irá executar considerando apenas o `gc_maxlifetime`:

```c
if (immediate) {
    PS(mod)->s_gc(&PS(mod_data), PS(gc_maxlifetime), &num);
    return num;
}
```

Vale notar que o GC baseado em probabilidade tem alguns poucos problemas, como:

1. Os dados de sessão de sites de baixo tráfego não podem ser excluídos dentro na duração desejada (inclusive *cPanel* possui uma ferramenta para supostamente resolver isso de tempos em tempos [*clean_user_php_sessions*](https://docs.cpanel.net/whm/scripts/the-clean_user_php_sessions-script/)).
2. O GC em sites de alto tráfego podem ser executados com muita frequência.
3. Quando o GC é realizado a pedido do usuário, o usuário experimentará um atraso no GC.

Portanto, conforme a [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-gc.php), é recomendado executar o GC periodicamente para sistemas de produção usando, por exemplo, `CRON` para sistemas do *UNIX-like*. Nesse caso é importante desabilitar o sistema baseado por probabilidades, definindo no `php.ini`:

```
session.gc_probability=0
```

Comment: Então no meu caso, `gc_probability=0` teria 0% de chances de executar o GC? Além disso, executar o `session_destroy()` em um logout, é uma boa ideia?

Comment: @CypherPotato sim (teoricamente), não é documentado que a probabilidade de 1% seria o minimo (posso olhar o php-src com calma para ter certeza depois). De qualquer forma arquivos de sessão as vezes abarrotam o servidor (mais por erro do dev que do PHP), por isso alguns servidores que usam cpanel tem uma função chamada [`clean_user_php_sessions`](https://docs.cpanel.net/whm/scripts/the-clean_user_php_sessions-script/) (eu pessoalmente desconfio da qualidade dos resultados após usa-la)

Comment: @CypherPotato já confirmei, gc_probability=0 desliga a probabilidade, ficando a seu cargo fazer o processo manual de execução do GC (como sugestão da documentação, usando CRON) e separei as partes do php-src para mostrar a diferença dos comportamentos.